# Need to Display all 3 sections at the center

Tags: html, css

Now We have a section it is looking like below image. Means **Cart Subtotal** is displaying left, **Checkout & View Shopping cart** is displaying at right.

[image]

Before its looking like this :

[image]

I want to display all [ Cart Subtotal , Checkout & View Shopping cart ] in center as like above image

```
 .header-minicart .subtotal {
        background-color: #DDDDDD;
        text-align: center;
        line-height: 2em;
    }

    @media only screen and (min-width: 1224px)
    .header-minicart .subtotal .label {
        color: #000;
        font-size: 14px;
        font-weight: normal;
        text-transform: capitalize;
    }

    @media only screen and (min-width: 1224px)
    .header-minicart .subtotal .price {
        color: #000;
        font-size: 14px;
        font-weight: normal;
    }

.header-minicart .minicart-actions .checkout-button {
    min-width: 145px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add below css

```
p.subtotal {
    float: none;
}
```

It will solve your issue.